# How to configure external authorisation in owncloud with External user support app?

Tags: ftp, authorization, owncloud

I'm testing owncloud. It is very nice system. I have to test authentication with ftp server with plugin "External user support". When I enable it in web admin panel nothing is happening. I don't know where to set up things that will enable authorization with my ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of ownCloud you are using, see either

- http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/configuration/custom_user_backend.html
  or
- http://doc.owncloud.org/server/4.5/admin_manual/custom_user_backend.html